# i have a functions which call other functions in different CFC through mapping

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I have few functions which i am trying to call from other CFCs using mappings

but i had clutterred all functions with external functions calls like this:

```
function a() {
b = new mynewpage.cfc.functionb(arguments);
}
function c() {
c = new mynewpage.cfc.pages.functionc(arguments);
}
```

so i am trying to focus on creating one function called as `invokeme`

```
function invokeme() {
c = new mynewpage.cfc.pages.functionc(arguments);
b = new mynewpage.cfc.functionb(arguments);
}
```

nut my question is how can use the `invokeme` function to use in function a and function b

should i use `invokeme.b.a()`

Comment: Have you looked at the `invoke` keyword? It might be closer to what you are trying to do.

Comment: i know about invoke: so what basically i am trying to say is: better to write a function which returns me an object and i can use that object's instance in my following functions instead of createobject in every single function i have

Comment: inviokeme is my function name, its not CFMl invoke: i am trying to make sure you understand what i am saying instead of we just ending no where

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work. I'm not 100% sure though in your context because I don't know what those other functions are doing.

```
function invokeme(args) {
    return {
        b = new mynewpage.cfc.functionb(argumentCollection=arguments.args);
    }
}
invokeme(someArguments).b.a; //Assuming b returns a component or object.
```

For example: https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=0def2e60-5ae3-466e-96de-f80bbbd2d78a/302995b7-ed73-48eb-bf97-598d4a825058/9184f40d-05b5-464e-ae49-45450787edf5.cfm

Essentially you nee to return the instance out of the function for use so the result of invokeme will be keys which are references to those instances. Then you can call them. I think this slightly complicates your code. I think it's cleaner to assign the instances explicitly instead of hidden in a function.